# $('#' + somestring).anything not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Afternoon, the current website I'm coding dynamically gets articles from the server and inserts them into a scrolling table, but I'm having issues keeping track of them

```
function addArticle() {

var div = document.createElement("div");

 var id="div"+count.toString();
 div.id=id;

 $('#'+id).load("http://localhost:8080/dog/demo.html"+count.toString(),function()   {});


 document.getElementById("newsfeed_table").rows[0].appendChild(div);
 count++;
}
```

Now if I set *all* the div's id's to  "div1" then the articles load, if I what I'm doing here, $('#'+id) it doesn't work, it doesn't throw errors either though, and the above is the problem, cause i've tested that string concatenation as a Jquery id on other things inn my page and it fails. ANY help appreciated.

Comment: You can't append a div to a table row directly. If you'd peek the created markup, you'd notice, that the divs are appended after the table. You've to create a cell first, and then append the div to that cell.

Comment: Your selector doesn't work because your targeting an element that has not been attached to the DOM yet therefor it cannot be found. The element must be part of the DOM for the selector query to work.

Comment: @vlaz count is clearly a variable that increment and used to create new unique ids

Comment: And do you have `demo.html2`, `demo.html33` etc? Seems like a strange way to name files ?

Comment: lol no, server fetches article N using xml from dog/demo.htmlN, anyone know the answer to my question in the comments of the first answer?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery selector $ is going throught DOM and find your selector. You are first searching for selector '#' + id which does not exist and then you are inserting newly created element into DOM. Try to swap this operations:

```
function addArticle() {

    var div = document.createElement("div");

    var id="div"+count.toString();
    div.id=id;

    document.getElementById("newsfeed_table").rows[0].appendChild(div);

    $('#'+id).load("http://localhost:8080/dog/demo.html"+count.toString(),function()   {});


    count++;
}
```

or try to use normal ajax function for GET https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ and in callback insert data into your newly created element and then insert it into a DOM.

```
function addArticle() {

    var div = document.createElement("div");

    var id="div"+count.toString();
    div.id=id;

    $.get( "http://localhost:8080/dog/demo.html"+count.toString(), function( data ) {
        $( div ).html( data );
    });

    document.getElementById("newsfeed_table").rows[0].appendChild(div);

    count++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but unfortunaty i have this issue now, the articles I load load from box.html, <p id="post_#dog#">#post#</p>, the server replaces the #tag# with data, BUT http://imgur.com/a/FFfGJ as seen here, when i click "read more" code is alert("#post_#dog#"); , it alerts the id of the _first_ article added, any idea why?

Comment: is it possible to publish whole solution somewhere? Is it realy hard to say, what went wrong.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/e0WZn here is image with all revelant code, if you click on the image and then zoom to 150% on chrome you can read the code, yellow highlighted is the most important, Thank you so much :D